Problem with my Google App Script review (Blocking with Consent Screen)
I am developing an App Script application, which I plan to publish on the Google Marketplace. To do this, I need to get the "OAuth consent screen" approved before submitting my application for review by Google.
The issue I'm facing is that the Google reviewer is asking for a process to test the OAuth consent screen. However, the consent screen is only accessible through my App Script application, which cannot be externally accessed until it is verified.
Did I miss something? How should I explain or demonstrate the testing process for the consent screen in this situation?
I've tried inviting it to my Google script, but it doesn't work because it's restricted to accounts in the same domain.

Please make a minimal reproducible example that can be copy/paste/run without changes to illustrate the issue.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The code isn't important, it's more a question of the procedure for validating an App Script that requires a review of the consent screen. How do I give the Google team access to my App Script?

Are you verifying your application? Based on this article, you need to provide a demonstration of the functionality by providing a demo video.

Seems like a question for Google, not Stack Overflow. See Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?

To make your OAuth Consent Screen approve, you need to submit a demo video illustrating the flow that explains the information of the requested scopes or data to Users.

Note: Google uses OAuth 2.0 for user permissions and consent, which enables developers to specify the type, and level of access required for their app to function via strings known as API scopes.

Here are some helpful links:

OAuth App Verification Help Center
Submit for OAuth verification (Public apps only)
Verification requirements

